# Pandas - OR condition in joining 2 datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Pretty New to Pandas

I have 2 datasets , example data :

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
A ANN BXX 9
B YYY NNN 10
C UUU DAF 11



C7 C8 C9 
N PP   C
B KK  68
F UUU  A
```

Desired output :

```
A ANN UUU
B YYY KK
C UUU PP
```

I need to join datasets in following fasion of sql query :

```
select C1 , C2,C8 from tab1 A, tab2  B where  (A.C1 = B.C7 or A.C1 = B.C9);
```

In short I need to merge 2 datsets either if C1 = C7 or C1 = C9. I understand how to join with one condition.

Something like :

```
OuT = pd.merge(tab1 , tab2 , left_on = 'C1', right_on =['C7' OR 'C9'], how = 'inner')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need reshape `tab2` by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
tab2 = tab2.melt('C8', value_name='C1').drop('variable', axis=1)
#older pandas versions
#tab2 = pd.melt(tab2, id_vars='C8', value_name='C1').drop('variable', axis=1)

print (tab2)
    C8  C1
0   PP   N
1   KK   B
2  UUU   F
3   PP   C
4   KK  68
5  UUU   A

#inner join by default, so can omit how='inner'
OuT = pd.merge(tab1 , tab2 , on = 'C1')
print (OuT)
  C1   C2   C3  C4   C8
0  A  ANN  BXX   9  UUU
1  B  YYY  NNN  10   KK
2  C  UUU  DAF  11   PP
```

and then if need filter columns:

```
OuT = pd.merge(tab1 , tab2 , on = 'C1')[['C1','C2','C8']]
print (OuT)
   C1   C2   C8
0  A  ANN  UUU
1  B  YYY   KK
2  C  UUU   PP
```

Comment: Trying to understand melt , Thanks a lot. It saved  of my time :)